# How to avoid looping multiple times with dynamically created elements - pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, toggle

I'm building a simple to do list using only javascript.
I know how to achieve the desired result with jQuery.

I've created a function that puts a line-through as  text-decoration in done tasks.

For that I'm trying to select the the dynamically added "li" elements with querySelectorAll.
Then, looping through the selection, I've added an addEventListener whose "click" toggles the line-through effect.

I'm calling such function every time a new "li" element is added in the todo list.

Thus, the loop runs and the event is triggered many times, as the number of "li" elements grows in the list.

If it loops an odd number of times, the objective is "achieved". But,naturally, running an even number of times it doesn't work.

Is there a way to solve this situation using a for loop?
If not, what would be the best practice to achieve the desired result using only pure javascript.

```
const arrTask = [];

    let insertTask = document.querySelector("input");
    insertTask.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
      if(e.keyCode === 13){
        arrTask.push(insertTask.value);
        insertTask.value = "";
        listTasks()
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    
    const getUlist = document.querySelector("ul");
    
    function listTasks(){
      // Add task to the list
        let task = document.createElement("li");
        task.innerHTML = `${arrTask[arrTask.length-1]}<button class="btn btn-danger deletable"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>`
        getUlist.appendChild(task);
        task.classList = "list-group-item list-group-item-action taskContainer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";
        markTasks();
        deleteButton();
    }
    
    function markTasks(){
      // Mark done tasks
      let listItem = document.querySelectorAll(".taskContainer");
      for(item of listItem){
        item.addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("mark")
        console.log(this)
        })
      }
    }
```

My code:
https://codepen.io/minatogawa/pen/oNbOqXp?editors=0011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When altering the html DOM, try to focus on the the actual objects. If you maintain references to the objects, updating and deleting them is much easier and no searching is required. It also makes the code smaller and cleaner.

Here is the updated code for your task list:

```
// Pure JS
const arrTask = [];

const nowUSee = () => {
  let addNew = document.querySelector(".fa-plus");
  let getInput = document.querySelector(".typeTask")
  addNew.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    getInput.classList.toggle("d-none")
  })
}
nowUSee();

let insertTask = document.querySelector("input");
insertTask.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    addTask(insertTask.value);  // append task object to list
    insertTask.value = "";  // reset text field
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent submit
  }
})

const getUlist = document.querySelector("ul");  // todo list

function addTask(txt) {
  let task = document.createElement("li");  // create task html element
  task.innerHTML = `${txt}<button class="btn btn-danger deletable"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>`  // text and delete button
  getUlist.appendChild(task);  // add task element to list element
  task.classList = "list-group-item list-group-item-action taskContainer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"; // classes for task element
  task.addEventListener("click", function(){  // add event for toggling strikethrough
        this.classList.toggle("mark")  // class for strikethrough
  })
  task.children[0].addEventListener('click', function(){  // add button event for deleting task
      getUlist.removeChild(task)
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey @Mike67 thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for. A cleaner way to do it using only javascript. Also I've updated the code, and provided some use for the array, aiming further improvements. Once more, thank you for the tips.  https://codepen.io/minatogawa/pen/oNbOqXp?editors=0010